# R loop to generate multiple variables based on a condition

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

The data is given as below.

```
x1<- c(1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0)
x2<- c(1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0)
x3<- c(1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0)
x4<- c(1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0)
x5<- c(1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0)
x6<- c(1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0)

my_data <- as.data.frame(cbind(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6))
```

I want to use a loop to automate the following process:

```
my_data$a1 = ifelse(my_data$x1> 0 & is.na(my_data$x1) != T, 1, 0)
my_data$a2 = ifelse(my_data$x2> 0 & is.na(my_data$x2) != T, 1, 0)
my_data$a3 = ifelse(my_data$x3> 0 & is.na(my_data$x3) != T, 1, 0)
my_data$a4 = ifelse(my_data$x4> 0 & is.na(my_data$x4) != T, 1, 0)
my_data$a5 = ifelse(my_data$x5> 0 & is.na(my_data$x5) != T, 1, 0)
my_data$a6 = ifelse(my_data$x6> 0 & is.na(my_data$x6) != T, 1, 0)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code -

```
my_data[paste0('a', seq_along(my_data))] <-  +(my_data > 0 & !is.na(my_data))
my_data

#  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6
#1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
#2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#5  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
#6  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
#7  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
#8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

This will assign 1 where the value is greater than 0 and is not `NA`. `my_data > 0 & !is.na(my_data)` returns a logical value (`TRUE`/`FALSE`) adding `+` ahead of it turns them to integers (`1`/`0`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use following for loop

```
for (i in 1:ncol(my_data)) {
 
   my_data[,paste0("a",i)] <- ifelse(my_data[,i] > 0 & !is.na(my_data[,i]),1,0)
  
}
```

Output

```
  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
6  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
7  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <-  my_data %>% 
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ +(. > 0 & !is.na(.)), 
     .names = "a{.col}")) %>% 
    rename_with(~ str_remove(., 'x'), starts_with('a'))
df
  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
6  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
7  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

**data.table**

```r
x1<- c(1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0)
x2<- c(1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0)
x3<- c(1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0)
x4<- c(1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0)
x5<- c(1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0)
x6<- c(1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0)

my_data <- as.data.frame(cbind(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6))
library(data.table)
setDT(my_data)[, (paste0("a", seq_len(length(names(my_data))))) := lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(x > 0 & !is.na(x), 1, 0))][]
#>    x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6
#> 1:  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
#> 2:  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#> 3:  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#> 4:  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#> 5:  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
#> 6:  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
#> 7:  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
#> 8:  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>